# ORA-01122: database file 1 failed verification check

Tags: oracle

I moved data file and database started fine but I did the following steps:

```
SQL> shutdown
SQL> startup nomount
SQL> alter system set control_files='/var/oracle/oradata/control.dbf' scope=spfile;
# shut immediate
# chown oracle:dba /var/oracle/oradata/control.dbf
# chmod 755 /var/oracle/oradata/control.dbf
# su – oracle
sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> startup

Total System Global Area 1068937216 bytes  
Fixed Size                  2233344 bytes  
Variable Size             813698048 bytes  
Database Buffers          247463936 bytes  
Redo Buffers                5541888 bytes  
Database mounted.  

ORA-01122: database file 1 failed verification check  
ORA-01110: data file 1: '/var/oracle/oradata/system.dbf'  
ORA-01207: file is more recent than control file - old control file
```

and now I'm unable to resolve this error.

Comment: what did you move from where to where? How did you move it?

Answer (score 1):

The SCN in the data file is greater than the SCN in the control file or wrong control file is being used. Please use correct control file.

If the the control fle is correct then do `BACKUP CONTROLFILE RECOVERY`.

Steps:

```
SQL>startup mount

SQL> recover database using backup controlfile until cancel;
```

it will ask you for archive logs, give the path of all archive logs which it needs until it gives you message,

```
MEDIA RECOVERY COMPLETED.
```

Open the database.

```
SQL> alter database open;
```

Comment: Thanks Shamim but is there any way to check path of all archive logs?

Comment: I am still waiting for your reply

Comment: Sorry for late. Actually I am on vacation. You can find the path of all archive log from this query - select name,thread#,sequence#,first_time,next_time,completion_time,archived from V$ARCHIVED_LOG order by FIRST_TIME desc